# Code contracts can't prove that elment exists in list

Tags: c#, .net, code-contracts, post-conditions

Basically, I want an element added to the list if it does not already exist in it. It seems reasonable to have a post-condition that ensures that this element exists in the list after method is done. Below is minimal example which gives me error "CodeContracts: ensures unproven: _numbers.Contains(n)". Any ideas why it does not work or if there is a way to rewrite the code to make it work?

```
class Test
{
    private List<int> _numbers = new List<int>();

    public void Add(int n)
    {
        Contract.Ensures(_numbers.Contains(n));
        if (!_numbers.Contains(n))
        {
            _numbers.Add(n);
        }
    }
    [ContractInvariantMethod]
    void ObjectInvariants()
    {
        Contract.Invariant(_numbers != null);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the code above and it seems to run perfect. I have negated the contracts just to prove they are running and they throw errors as expected. What version of visual studio are you running?

Comment: I am running it on VS15. What do you mean that when running this code errors get thrown as expected? Is the code I wrote is actually incorrect and errors should be thrown?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I meant I changed 'Contract.Ensures( _numbers.Contains(n) );' to 'Contract.Ensures( ! _numbers.Contains(n) );' and an error was thrown as it should do. I think your code in correct (Worked for me on VS15).

Comment: Maybe your code contracts is not update? In the project properties, what code contract settings have you selected?